# Can $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac {\sin(\frac {k\pi}2)}{k!}x^k$ be the $n$th Maclaurin polynomial of $\sin x$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

When finding an expression for the $n$th Maclaurin polynomial for $\sin x$, I have given $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac {\sin(\frac {k\pi}2)}{k!}x^k$, as the successive derivatives of $\sin x $ at $0$, i.e. $0,1, 0, -1, 0 \ldots$ are the values of $\sin x$ at successive intervals of $\pi \over 2$. However, I am unsure as to whether my expression is correct because the Maclaurin polynomial for $\sin x$ is always given to me as $\sum _{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac {x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$. Is this last sum merely a better representation, or is it the case that the sum I have come up with is incorrect?

Comment: Since $\sin(\frac {k\pi}2)$ is $0, 1,0,-1,...$ then yes, of course.

Comment: The $n$-th Maclaurin polynomial is the one you have given first, while the latter one would be its $(2n+1)$-th polynomial technically. But otherwise they're just the same expansion, just with the coefficients being the same but written differently, as the other comments have pointed out already.